# How to get the offset of a struct member in Rust? (offsetof)

Tags: rust

C has `offsetof`, is there some way to do this in Rust?

Even though the order may change between compilations (unless `repr(C)` is used), for a given complication it should be possible to access the offset of a `struct` member at compile time.

Whats the best way find this offset in Rust?

Comment: If having to create an instance of the struct is acceptable, you can do `&foo.bar as *const _ as usize - &foo as *const _ as usize` to get the offset of the field `bar`.

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of doesn't provide a convenient replacement for `offsetof`, nor should it - since its asking a related but different question.